# Parsing iCal feed with multiple events with Python and vobject

Tags: python, icalendar, vobject

I'm trying to parse a feed with multiple events and its only returning me one item

```
ics = urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/pcolalug%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics").read()
events = []

components = vobject.readComponents(ics)
for event in components:
    to_zone = tz.gettz('America/Chicago')

    date = event.vevent.dtstart.value.astimezone(to_zone)
    description = event.vevent.description.value

    events.append({
                'start': date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT),
                'description': description if description else 'No Description', 
                })

return {'events': events[:10]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switched to using icalendar instead of vobject, it works a lot better.

```
ics = urllib.urlopen("https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/pcolalug%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics").read()
events = []

cal = Calendar.from_string(ics)

for event in cal.walk('vevent'):
    to_zone = tz.gettz('America/Chicago')

    date = event.get('dtstart').dt.astimezone(to_zone)
    description = event.get('description')

    events.append({
                'start': date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT),
                'description': description if description else 'No Description', 
                })

return {'events': events[:10]}
```

Comment: icalendar is not available as package in linux. It is verymuch possible with vobject.

Comment: Thats not true, you just "pip install icalendar" and it works.  Its pure python and has no C extensions so it works on all platforms.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/3.11.4